# Clojure, raynes.fs, iterate-dir: a cryptic file-related data structure

Tags: file, clojure, filesystems

I'm trying to traverse a filesystem tree using iterate-dir function from raynes.fs library: https://github.com/Raynes/fs/blob/master/src/me/raynes/fs.clj

Everything makes sense, except for the "File" part of the returned sequence of vectors (I tried to catch output from the clipboard and define a variable of it for research purposes):

```
(def res ([#<File /home/alexey/dir-src> #{"3" "4" "1" "2" "10"} #{"Фото-0015.jpg"}]
      [#<File /home/alexey/dir-src/1> #{} #{"vB8vqyc4XBk.jpg" "valet.jpg"}]
      [#<File /home/alexey/dir-src/10> #{} #{"jca3.jpg" "jca10.jpg" "jca1.jpg" "jca4.jpg" "jca2.jpg"}]
      [#<File /home/alexey/dir-src/2> #{"002"} #{"warrior-babe-305079.jpg" "wallp_fant_0017.jpg"}]
      [#<File /home/alexey/dir-src/2/002> #{} #{"tumblr_mt7rckyTbi1qd5ic3o1_500.jpg"}]
      [#<File /home/alexey/dir-src/3> #{} #{"Сияние-cosplay-931717.jpeg"}]
      [#<File /home/alexey/dir-src/4> #{} #{}]))

clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: Unreadable form :: {:column 14, :line 27, :type :reader-exception}
```

The error also makes perfect sense, as there's no data structure literals like #< ... > in Clojure. I do need the paths for mapping and sorting, but I have no idea how to access them. By the way, the standard compare function gets accepted:

```
(sort compare (fs/iterate-dir path))
```

the sequence above *is* sorted, though not quite the way I want it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `File` objects are standard `java.io.File` instances.

You can look up `java.io.File` in javadoc to find the operations that can be done on a `File`.

Like most java classes, it has no Clojure read support, so it must be created via constructor calls (ie. `(java.io.File. ".")` to get a `File` for the current directory).

As the doc for `iterate-dir` mentions, it will return a sequence of every node in the tree starting with the input. You can ignore the `File` if it does not have anything you want in it. Likely, at each node you would want to know the path to that node though.

```
user> (java.io.File. ".")
#<File .>
user> (.getCanonicalPath (java.io.File. "."))
"/home/noisesmith/example/"
```